# How do I move a world save onto my minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to play an adventure map with my friends but want to do it over my server so we don't need to use "Lan". How would I move the map into my server from my desktop?

Comment: We need more info, please. Is this server run on your computer, or is it a server that you purchased access for?

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2, its not because I already have the server and want the map on the preexisting server.

Comment: And it is run from my computer, I made it

Comment: If that is the case, the answer should work.

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 Let's not dupe to a closed question, shall we?  Even if it's a duplicate, a closed question should be deleted, not duped to.

Comment: @Frank Then this post should be closed, like the duplicate was. The person asking the question needs somewhere else to ask this, since he really doesn't know what is happening.

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 Why should it be closed?  Does it meet one of the close reasons?  Is it an off-topic question?  I don't think you're quite understanding what's being asked.

Comment: @Frank Whatever. Go ahead and try to help him. The problem he has is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 There's a reason you need 3K rep before you can close questions.  So you can learn what Arqade is all about, and what our norms are.  There's *nothing* here that justifies a closure.  A dupe, maybe, if it had been asked before.  But what's being asked is rather straightforward; moving a map from one computer to another.  That's it, that's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26166/discussion-between-tkdestroyer2-and-frank).

Comment: @Smartypants1800 You should elaborate more on 'server' and your exact setup. We cannot help until more information is given.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm going to assume that you're running the server on your computer.**

To use a map on a server, all you have to do is navigate into your *saves* directory within .minecraft, copy the folder containing the map you wish to use and paste it into the server directory's saves folder.

After that, you will need to modify this line in the *server.properties* file:

```
level-name=world
```

Change 'world' to whatever the name of your map folder is.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you, but, where can I find the server directory?

Comment: Ive got the server files, but the server directory is not there, i cant configure anything

Comment: no, thats the problem

Comment: @Smartypants1800 All server files will be next to, and in the same folder as, your minecraft server file (the one you run to start the server, which you downloaded from the Minecraft website).

Comment: i run the server from a Jar not a folder

Comment: and I have started my server

Comment: hold on, let me check something

Comment: @Smartypants1800 I don't know how you are running the server from a .jar, but [the Minecraft download page](https://minecraft.net/download) has a .exe file for running servers. That is what you need for a 'dedicated' server (one the runs independently of the Minecraft application).

Comment: hey, I replaced the "world" folder with the map I wanted and changed the level-world and am runing the server but the map is not loading in, please help, Im really confused

Comment: @Smartypants1800 You should [check this guide out.](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server) It has a step-by-step list.

Comment: @Smartypants1800 Note that you need to name the world "world" or change the settings of the server, which might be complicated if you don't see a properties file.

Comment: I think the problem is that I dont have a saves foler in my server directory, should I?

Comment: @Smartypants1800 Probably not. The world should work, but if it doesn't, the server created a new world called "world" if you didn't change any settings. Be wary of that when you are changing the name of your world's folder.

Comment: and I did rename and everything

Comment: THATS EXACTALY WHAT HAPENDED!!!!! but i rename

Comment: @Smartypants1800 If you deleted the world that your server created and you replaced it and it still won't work, then you should check your minecraft version. The world could be an older version.

Comment: Dude Im so sorry, i forgot to save, im so stupid, let me go save and try it and than ill get back to you'

Comment: THANK YOU, ALL OF YOU GUYS FOR BEARING WITH ME BUT I GOT IT TO WORK, I REALLY APPRECIATE THE HELP, AND JUST WANTED TO SAY THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!